# .htaccess rename rule for rewrite but internally append

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL of the form `www.aroundnext.org/Scholastic/Home` , how may I change it to `www.aroundnext.org/Home` whilst internally appending `Scholastic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Scholastic/Home/(.*)$ /Home/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This redirects files in a old directory ([www.aroundnext.org/Scholastic/Home](http://www.aroundnext.org/Scholastic/Home)) to a new directory ([www.aroundnext.org/Home](http://www.aroundnext.org/Home)). The file must exist in the new directory to function.